Using a Pi 4b to modify frequency of 12v pulsed input and send as an output signal
I am working on a project that requires fitment of a cruise control unit from one car into a different car. Both cars send the cruise control units their speed in different ways, therefore I need to intercept and modify the signal to change its frequency and therefore allow it to be understood by the cruise control unit from the different car.
The car in question sends its speed signal at ~4000 pulses per mile (i.e 32.83hz at 30mph)
The cruise control unit I want to fit expects a speed signal at either ~6000 or ~8000 pulses per mile, I am unsure of which, thus the need for using a Pi rather than a fixed circuit so I can change the frequency multiplier.
The input signal is square wave, automotive, so should be 12-14v, but may spike higher than that. The GPIO pins are limited to 3v, current draw should be minimal.
How can I go about doing this? Is this even possible at all with a Pi 4b?

Possible, with correct electronics and code - have you considered a cheap microcontroller instead

Suggest you consider editing your question. As currently written, it sounds like you don't actually have a clue what you need to do  :/   If you want help, you'll need to be more specific.

I thought I was pretty clear. I need to use a Pi to act as a frequency multiplier on a 12-14v square wave signal.
